# How to check if widget is a checkbox in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Im theming my forms i want dont show the label if the field is a checkbox

```
{% form_theme form with _self %}

{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="mygroup">
            {{form_label(form)}} # hide if checkbox
            {{form_errors(form)}}
            {{form_widget(form)}}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: if i've checked i cant find anything

Comment: I think `{% if widget == 'checkbox' %}` should work.

Comment: @mahok i get a error `Variable "widget" does not exist in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a while i found solution in [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/nIoWHEMKzVE)

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="mygroup">
        {% if 'checkbox' not in form.vars.block_prefixes %}
        {{form_label(form)}}
        {% endif %}
        {{form_errors(form)}}
        {{form_widget(form)}}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```